# How get trainable variable count when using Tf Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a CNN classifier model using the tf estimator framework. However, I could not access variables defined in the model. tf.trainable_variables() always return 0.
  How can i access variables using tf estimator? In particular, how can i get a count of the total number of parameters (adding up the dimensions of all variables.

Thanks,
Harold

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you should use:

- [`tf.estimator.Estimator.get_variable_names()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_names) in order to get all estimator variables
- [`tf.estimator.Estimator.get_variable_value(name)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value) in order to get variables values

Once you have the variables, you can use one of the following ways in order to get the total number of estimator parameters.

- Either multiply the shape dims of each one of the variables with [`numpy.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) and then sum it:

  `sum([np.prod(est.get_variable_value(var).shape) for var in est.get_variable_names()])`
- Or sum the sizes of the variables with [`numpy.ndarray.size`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) and then sum it:

  `sum([est.get_variable_value(var).size for var in est.get_variable_names()])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_variable_names()` to get all variable names,
and use `get_variable_value(name)` to get the variable value by name.

Please use your code like:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(...)
params = estimator.get_variable_names()
for p in params:
    print(p, estimator.get_variable_value(p).shape)
```

The more information is https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_names
and 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value.

Note: you must create the graph first and then will get the variables.